# window.returnValue rework for chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a java date picker and it is not passing back the value in chrome. I think its is due to the js using window.returnvalue. How would i fix this?

```
 // Allow the browser to save/pass the date selected and close the window.
    protected void calDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      string closeWindow = @"
                <script language='javascript'>
                    window.returnValue='###date###';
                    window.close();
                </script>";

      closeWindow = closeWindow.Replace("###date###", calDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());

      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CloseWindow", closeWindow);
    }
```

Comment: java !== javascript. Do you actually have a javascript date picker? In which case, which one? Also, your event handler appears to be C# code in a ASP.NET Web Forms project, which is important information to tag your question with.